# Finding most common word in text

Tags: python

need to write a function that will return the most common word in the text.

Comment: You need to make an attempt first. Get a pen and paper, and write out each step in pseudo code. This is pretty basic once you get the idea. Also if you're allowed to use imports, look into [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects).

Comment: I Googled your question's exact title and found many useful results. Adding "python" to the query produced more specific results, including the linked duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
from collections import Counter
word=("he thought a thought that he thought he'd never think")
word=word.split(' ')
Counter(word)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'thought': 3, 'he': 2, 'a': 1, "he'd": 1, 'that': 1, 'never': 1,      
'think': 1})
```

Now, you can sort it in descending order using 'value' and you will get the most common words.

Comment: I appreciate the time you put into your answer, but questions where the OP shows no effort should be closed not answered.